# Hive Index Creation failed

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am using hive version 3.1.0 in my project I have created one external table using below command.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testing(ID int,DEPT int,NAME string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

I am trying to create an index for the same external table using the below command.

```
CREATE INDEX index_test ON TABLE testing(ID)
AS 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.index.compact.CompactIndexHandler'
WITH DEFERRED REBUILD ;
```

But I am getting below error.

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:7 cannot recognize input near 'create' 'index' 'user_id_user' in ddl statement (state=42000,code=40000)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Hive documentation, Hive indexing is removed since version 3.0

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Indexing#LanguageManualIndexing-IndexingIsRemovedsince3.0